# I am stuck on an asp.net login form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created asp.net login form. The problem is that I want to check if the username exists in the SQL database, but I can't even connect to the database. The error message is:

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int.`

This is my code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblmessage.Visible = false;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lblsec.Text = Userutility.generateSecurity();
    }
}

protected void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtusername.Text =="" || txtpassword.Text=="" || TextBox2.Text ==""|| sec_code.Text == "" )
    {
        lblmessage.Text = "لطفا فیلد هارا پر کنید";
        lblmessage.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtusername.Text,@"^[a-zA-Z]{5,50}$"))
    {
        lblmessage.Text = "نام کاربری باید حداقل 5 کاراکتر و از کاراکتر های مجاز استفاده شود";
        lblmessage.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtmail.Text, @"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"))
    {
        lblmessage.Text = "ایمیل وارد شده معتبر نمی باشد";
        lblmessage.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (txtpassword.Text != TextBox2.Text)
    {
        lblmessage.Text = "کلمه عبور شما تطابق ندارد";
        lblmessage.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (Userutility.user_login_exist(txtusername.Text))
    {
        lblmessage.Text = "این نام کاربری موجود میباشد";
        lblmessage.Visible = true;

    }
    else if (Convert.ToInt16(sec_code.Text) != Convert.ToInt16(Session["sec_code"].ToString()))
    {
        lblmessage.Text = "عبارت امنیتی صحیح نمی باشد";
        lblsec.Text = Userutility.generateSecurity();
        lblmessage.Visible = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EnglishDB;Integrated Security=true");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection=cnn;
        string sql = @"Insert into student (Username,FirstName,LastName,Age,Major,City,Country,Password,Email,Cellphone)";
        sql += " VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}')";
        sql = string.Format(sql, txtusername, txtlastname, txtlastname, txtage, txtmajor, txtcity, txtcountry, txtpassword, txtmail, txtcellphone);
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `username` column in your database?

Comment: Advice: Don't use string.Format for parameters, that is bad practice. You should use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx for parameters.

Comment: On what line do you get this error?  Also, please look into using parameterized queries.  Currently your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: david i have created   this method  public static string sanitize_Sql(string input)
        {
            return input.Replace("'", "''");
        }

Comment: Ricky username type is nvarchar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not mentioned `.Text` property for the TextBoxes in sql query. Instead you are mentioning control names.

```
string.Format(sql, txtusername.Text ...
```

Better approach is to use **parameterized query** instead.

```
 using( SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EnglishDB;Integrated Security=true"))
 {
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection=cnn;
    string sql = @"Insert into student (Username,FirstName,LastName,Age,Major,City,Country,Password,Email,Cellphone)";
    sql += " VALUES(@Username,@FirstName,@LastName,@Age,@Major,@City,@Country,@Password,@Email,@Cellphone)";


    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Username, txtusername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@FirstName, txtfirstname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@LastName, txtlastname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Age, txtage.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Major, txtmajor.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@City, txtcity.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Country, txtcountry.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Password, txtpassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Email, txtmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Cellphone, txtcellphone.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();        
 }
```

It seems like you are giving value for `int` in single quote as well. [SqlCommand Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should solve all problems here.

Answer (score 0):

profiously your age field is of datatype `int`. you getting its value from a textBox, thus a string, so your are trying to insert a string to an int field

use:

```
int age=int.Parse(txtage);
```

and then pass it as parameter:

```
string sql = @"Insert into student(Username,FirstName,LastName,Age,Major,City,Country,Password,Email,Cellphone)  VALUES(@Usr,@Fname,@LastName,@Age,@Major,@City,@Country,@Pass,@Email,@Cell)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usr",txtusername);
//...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age",age);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing your part of the code with this.

```
string sql = @"Insert into student (Username,FirstName,LastName,Age,Major,City,Country,Password,Email,Cellphone)";
            sql += " VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}',{3},'{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}')";
            sql = string.Format(sql, txtusername.Text, txtlastname.Text, txtlastname.Text, txtage.Text, txtmajor.Text, txtcity.Text, txtcountry.Text, txtpassword.Text, txtmail.Text, txtcellphone.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you Very much . you dont know how much i am happy

Comment: sorry iam new in stack overflow , can you help what should i do ?

Comment: This is quite possibly the number one worst way to format a SQL string from code. Why? Well probably because SQL injection is the number one attack in the world and this query is the attackers best friend. The answer below by Hassan is MUCH better. You need to be parameterizing your variables before they go into your SQL string.

Comment: thank you Anthony. also i have class that forbid sql injection .